# Magento 2.3: saving configurable products lead to erasing price

Tags: product, configurable-product, price, magento2.3, products

When I create a new configurable product and then I add the configurations price field gets disabled and erased. Is there any way to fix this or just take the first configuration price?

Also in admin product listing the prices the price attribute is not present for configurable product.

This is the configurable product:

[image]
and this are its childs:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem

Check max_input_vars

Try this

```
.htaccess
php_value max_input_vars 4000

php.ini or .user.ini
max_input_vars = 4000
```

Comment: witch .htaccess should I edit ??

Comment: File in web root  where index.php is located

Comment: this is not really helping unfortunately.. we are also using cpanel and it dosen't help to edit there either.

Comment: If using cpanel the option is under MultiPHP Manager. Did you find it?

Comment: well yea its already set to 4000 and is still not working like this.